# Issue during installation and setup of october cms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am new to OctoberCMS, but familiar with laravel

While performing installation and setup via composer I am getting below error

[image]

I followed below steps to install octobercms
https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands

I have created that dir and gave it necessary permission, but still I am getting that error

I have also cleared cache by
`$ php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:cache && php artisan config:cache && php artisan view:clear`
but still error persist.

version

php - 7.0.33

"october/cms": "~1.0",

Kindly comment if more details are needed

Comment: What is the "necessary permission" you've given the folder? Also, where is it located and configured?

Comment: $ sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache

Comment: But the error says `storage/framework/cache` directory.

Comment: yes gave same permission to all required dir such as `bootstrap/cache` and `storage/framework/cache`

Comment: `$ sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache` this is written just to show permission details

Answer (score 0):

Try these in order

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan route:clear
$ php artisan cache:table
$ php artisan route:cache
$ php artisan config:cache
```

Seems like you haven't create migration for the cache database table.